# Unbound combobox doesn't show value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

hope you can help me, there are a lot of posts on this topic, but none matches my problem really.

I've got a WPF-Window with unbound text- and comboboxes. They're filled in a foreach-loop on load programmatically by c# code with values from an Xml-database.

```
switch (TypeOfSync)
                {
                    case SyncType.FromXmlDataBase:                            
                        MyControl.Text = MyXmlSubNode.InnerText;
                        break;
                    case SyncType.ToXmlDataBase:
                        MyXmlSubNode.InnerText = MyControl.Text;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
```

The target combobox may **not** be editable.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="OPReason">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content=""/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Erstimplantation"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Revision bis 3 Monate"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Revision"/>
                </ComboBox>
```

In all other comboboxes everything works well. Also in this box everything is ok, until the the code sets the text property to "Revision". Then nothing is displayed, even if return value of the text property shows the correct value.

Of course you will say now, choose a databinding approach, but other actions have to performed simultaneously, so this is not really an option. A bit misterious. Might the similar beginning of "Revision" and "Revision bis 3 Monate" be the problem??

Comment: Can't reproduce with the code you provided. By the way, I'm curious what mysterious operations you do, that stop you from doing the binding to ItemsSource.

Comment: Also - I don't understand this part - 'Also in this box everything is ok, until the the code sets the text property to "Revision". Then nothing is displayed, even if return value of the text property shows the correct value.'. What text property?

Comment: In this window there are also several user controls displaying values from the Xml database, which have to be manipulated by code.

Comment: If I choose "Erstimplantation" or "Revision bis 3 Monate" the values are "saved", "loaded" and displayed correctly. If "Revision" is chosen, the value is correctly "saved" and "loaded" (I have checked the text property value of the combobox), however the combobox stays empty.

Comment: Mike, what you describe here is a very typical scenario: load data and then display data. Nothing should stop you from writing that mvvm way - to load the data in your model, manipulate that data in viewmodel, display it with bindings. That way you'll write a code that will be maintainable in future, and it will be easy to ask questions on this site - without a need to show all your prioprietary code.

Comment: I give up :-), I managed it using your proposed way. Thx for the help, but I'm still curious where the problem was, though my solution worked well in previous versions...

Comment: Maybe you were setting control's properties from non-UI thread?

Comment: I do so, but this was the first time a problem appeared, and only when I'm using "Revision". Strange. However, with databindings everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filling text- and comboboxes manually by code from an XmlDatabases seems to be an susceptible way. Using databindings with a viewmodel is much safer and more reliable.